# How to add additional property counts to Grouped WPF Datagrid Items?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF app that communicates with a 3rd party app to gather updates from.
These updates are then put into a Updates Collection and displayed into a Datagrid.

The update class:

```
public class UpdateEntry
{
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeOfUpdate { get; set; }
    public string Reference { get; set; }
}
```

As per in this tutorial: http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html

I have grouped the results by the **UserName** field:

```
Updates = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(UserUpdates);
GroupedUpdates = new ListCollectionView(UserUpdates);
GroupedUpdates.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("UserName"));
```

and am able to show the number of updates entries as per the **ItemCount** property as shown here:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}" Margin="8,0,4,0"/>
<TextBlock Text="Updates"/>
```

What I would like to be able to do is also display a **Reference** ***Count***, next to this **UpdateEntry** ***Count***, ie. number of References per person (**UserName**).

FYI: There are multiple updates per Reference and per person.

I do have a User Summary Class which assists with populating the name and storing the number of Handled References per User, but I'm not sure how I would use this in context with the DataGrid:

```
public UserSummary(){ HandledReferences = new List<ReferenceInstance>();}

    public string UserID {get;set;}

    public string UserName {get;set;}

    public List<Models.ReferenceInstance> HandledReferences {get;set;}

    public int NumberOfReferences { get { return HandledReferences.Count; }}
```

*I've excluded some fields for simplicity and conciseness*

Here is an example of what I'd like to achieve:

**Bobby Boo - Updates: 4  References: 2**

- UserID: BB03, UserName: Bobby Boo, Time: 10:24, Reference: A11
- UserID: BB03, UserName: Bobby Boo, Time: 10:51, Reference: A11
- UserID: BB03, UserName: Bobby Boo, Time: 11:54, Reference: C99
- UserID: BB03, UserName: Bobby Boo, Time: 12:09, Reference: C99

**Mike Larry - Updates: 2  References: 1**

- UserID: NW01, UserName: Mike Larry, Time: 15:22, Reference: B22
- UserID: NW01, UserName: Mike Larry, Time: 17:12, Reference: B22

**Additional Info:**

Here is a bigger look at the Control Template on the Datagrid Grouping:

```
<DataGrid DockPanel.Dock="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedUpdates}" IsReadOnly="True" Background="LightSlateGray">
        <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Padding="3"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <Expander>
                                        <Expander.Header>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <StackPanel.Resources>
                                                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13" />
                                                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                                                    </Style>
                                                </StackPanel.Resources>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}" Margin="8,0,4,0"/>
                                                <TextBlock Text="Updates"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Expander.Header>
                                        <ItemsPresenter />
                                    </Expander>
                                </ControlTemplate>
```

and a screenshot of the double grouping / figures I'm trying to capture:

[image: UserName and Reference Groups Example]

Comment: you may perhaps join these two classes to make a new with the desired properties. if you may upload a sample of your app, I may want to give a try.

Answer (score 2):

If you can calculate `NumberOfReferences` just from the list of `UpdateEntry`, you can bind to `Items` in the control template for `GroupItem` and implement `IValueConverter` which returns the necessary value (`ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Object>` => `int`). FYI, data context is `CollectionViewGroup`.

If the logic is more complex, you can subclass `CollectionViewGroup` (and name it `UserSummary` if you like), then subclass `ListCollectionView` to use your groups, then implement whatever logic you need.

**XAML**

```
<Control.Resources>
    <local:ReferencesConverter x:Key="ConvertReferences"/>
</Control.Resources>
```

...

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}"/>
<TextBlock Text="Updates"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Items, Converter={StaticResource ConvertReferences}}"/>
<TextBlock Text="References"/>
```

**C#**

```
public class ReferencesConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        var collection = (ReadOnlyObservableCollection<object>)value;
        var updateEntries = collection.Cast<UpdateEntry>();

        // TODO Return number of references
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. Code not tested.
2. [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx). You can find more examples just by googling.
3. If you need deeper groups, check for types of items you receive in `Convert` method.

Comment: Could you please provide a more indepth example? as I've never had to use a IValueConverter before.
I've since discovered that adding another group below the 'UserName' group (as a 'Reference' group) added a new sublevel group which is also more desirable for what I'm trying to achieve.
Does your method allow to count the number of items in that sub group?

Comment: I've updated the description with a more detailed look at the control template, where would I bind to 'Items'? and where would I plug in the IValueConverter?